# Changing CSS font style and size doesn't have any effect

Tags: html, css, font-size, font-style

```css
* {
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
 font-family: Calibri;
}
#largefont{
 font-size: 24px;
 font-family: serif;
}
```

```html
<p id="largefont">
<p>TEXT text</p>
...
</p>
```

It's actually a live website I'm doing for a HTML/CSS class.  You can view it here:

http://user2cis133.achins.com/homework%20nov8/index.html

The basic code is at the top.  I set the `<p>` as `id="largefont"` and in the CSS doc I set the font family and size.  However the font size and style isn't changing.  I would like some help figuring out why it isn't working.

Comment: Where are you defining that it should be 1.1? i.e. how, in code, have you told the browser this? As far as I can tell, you have not implemented and CSS styles setting the font size.

Comment: Also you should define your question more thoroughly to yield a better response here. I think people will downvote this question because it is too generic. It is basically saying "I have a bug, can someone please fix it". You need to define the problem better. For example "I am setting the font size for an HTML element by... [doing this]... but it doesn't seem to be working. Here's a snippet of my code, and a link to a running example.

Comment: It's in a stylesheet: #largefont{
 font-size: 24px;
 font-family: serif;
}

It's in an attached style sheet.  http://user2cis133.achins.com/homework%20nov8/style.css

Comment: I added the main code.  Let me rewrite the question.

Comment: Much better! Now we can see the problem straight away. You cannot nest <p> elements.

Comment: Ahh thank you.  I wasn't aware of that.  I can I nest div tags?  Like in lieu of the paragraph tag can I put a div tag?  I need the font to change for everything BUT the header which is in the body tag.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, you can nest div elements. But why don't you just set a global font-size i.e. * {font-size:1.1em;} then set a specific font size for the header? Instead of the other way around...

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in one of your comments you are attempting to apply `font-size:24px` to a `<p>` element with `innerText='TEXT text'`.

Firstly; **`24px` is not the same as `1.1em` as per your question**. Please define your question more accurately lest we have to do ALL the work for you.

Your issue is that you have defined a CSS style rule for a particular ID, yet there is no element in your HTML document with this ID.

To make this work, with what you have, you need to give that `<p>` element the same id that is defined in your style.css rule:

```
<p id="largefont">TEXT text</p>
```

***EDIT: I just saw you did have another `<p>` element with that ID however it looks like you tried to nest the `<p>` elements which is not allowed, so the browser terminated the first `<p>` before it made it to the second one.***

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing the closing brace `}` of your first CSS rule.

```css
* {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    font-family: Calibri;
```

Add in the closing brace and it and your CSS should work properly.

```css
* {     
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    font-family: Calibri; 
}
```

Comment: No it's there, it just didn't copy over.

Comment: @BlindGuardian117 Then fix it in your question!

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> <p id="largefont">
> <p>TEXT text</p>
> ...
> </p>
> ```

The `<p>` element can not contain another `<p>`. Since `<p>` elements do not need a closing tag, your markup is the same as:

```
<p id="largefont"></p>
<p>TEXT text</p>
...
</p>
```

where the stray closing `</p>` tag is an error.

Your style for `largefont` is only applied to the first *empty* paragraph, not to the second.